# Data from parent node (tried former)

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I'm playing around with some XML based on the bookstore example at w3schools.com. The end result I'm hoping for is a list of bookstore, book, and title - the real use will be to parse some production XML data to plug it plug data into a database table that has a bunch of different sources - i.e. reduce a basic set of fields to the least common denominator.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <Bookstores>
      <Bookstore Storenameattribute="Barnes and Noble Attribute">
        <Storename>Barnes and Noble</Storename>
        <book category="WEB">
          <title lang="en">Learning XML</title>
          <author>Erik T. Ray</author>
          <year>2003</year>
          <price>39.95</price>
        </book>
        <book category="WEB">
          <title lang="en">XQuery Kick Start</title>
          <author>James McGovern</author>
          <author>Per Bothner</author>
          <author>Kurt Cagle</author>
          <author>James Linn</author>
          <author>Vaidyanathan Nagarajan</author>
          <year>2003</year>
          <price>49.99</price>
        </book>
      <Bookstore Storenameattribute="Amazon Attribute">
        <Storename>Amazon</Storename>
        <book category="WEB">
          <title lang="en">Learning XML</title>
          <author>Erik T. Ray</author>
          <year>2003</year>
          <price>39.95</price>
        </book>
    </Bookstores>

<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:csv="http://www.ora.com/XSLTCookbook/namespaces/csv">
<xsl:output method="text" />

<xsl:template match="/">
<xsl:for-each select="Bookstores/Bookstore">
<xsl:text>|StoreName|</xsl:text>
 <xsl:for-each select="book">


  <xsl:text>|Title|</xsl:text>
  <xsl:value-of select="title"/>
  <xsl:text>|Author|</xsl:text>
  <xsl:value-of select="author"/>
  <xsl:value-of select="ancestor::Bookstore[1]/@Storenameattribute">
  <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
 </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:for-each>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The line above with "ancestor" is based on a suggestion in another thread here. I've tried a variety of options including "../Bookstore@StoreNamesttribute", "../Bookstore/Storename"../Storename" and so on. They all give an error "Error Transforming XML 
XSLT compile error. The 'xsl:value-of' start tag on line 12 does not match the end tag of 'xsl:for-each'. Line 14, position 4. "

If I remove that line, I get

```
|StoreName||Title|Learning XML|Author|Erik T. Ray 
|Title|XQuery Kick Start|Author|James McGovern
```

which is closer to what I need - I'm hoping for

```
|StoreName|Barnes and Noble|Title|Learning XML|Author|Erik T. Ray 
|StoreName|Barnes and Noble|Title|XQuery Kick Start|Author|James McGovern
```

I know the "StoreName" column isn't repeated of course, because I have it outside the for-each at present.

In this particular case I have the Storename and Storenameattribute as separate things because I was trying to figure out which one would work (the real XML has a mix of elements and attributes that must be handled). I'm quite sure I'm missing something that will be *blindingly* obvious once people who know what they're doing have a glance at it!

Comment: Your syntax error is simply due to you having forgotten to close the `xsl:value-of` where you select `@Storenameattribute`.   Change `>` to `/>` there, and then let us know what problems remain.

Comment: Your XML is missing the closing tags for `Bookstore`.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm hoping for
>   |StoreName|Barnes and Noble|Title|Learning
>   XML|Author|Erik T. Ray
>   |StoreName|Barnes and Noble|Title|XQuery Kick
>   Start|Author|James McGovern

If that's your goal, you could use simply:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" />

<xsl:template match="/Bookstores">
    <xsl:for-each select="Bookstore/book">
        <xsl:text>|StoreName|</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="../Storename"/>
        <xsl:text>|Title|</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="title"/>
        <xsl:text>|Author|</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="author"/>
        <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>     
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

To get the value of `Storenameattribute` instead of `Storename` use:

```
<xsl:value-of select="../@Storenameattribute"/>
```

instead of:

```
<xsl:value-of select="../Storename"/>
```

Note that this requires a well-formed XML as the input - what you show us is not.

Comment: kjhughes: Well, I feel intelligent (not!) for missing the slash on the value-of. I was doing that consistently, too - no matter where I put the command or what variant, I was typing it manually and missed that step.  That did indeed solve the issue. 

Malformed XML = operator error - i just grabbed a snippet of what I'm actually using, and clearly didn't edit it correctly when I posted it. The actual XML I'm using is fine.

michael.hor257k - thanks for the alternate version of the xsl - I'm a newbie (obviously!) and I know there are often different ways of doing things.

Comment: FYI, the real fun will be the real data. It's constructed like this:
<book title="Harry Potter"><bookfact>author></bookfact><bookfact>published<published></bookfact></book> and my ultimate objective will be to get something like      "|Title|Harry Potter|Author|Rowling|Published|1995". Anyway, thanks both of you for your help.

Comment: @JOATMON "*That did indeed solve the issue*" I don't think so. Just fixing the errors on your XML and XSLT will result in (first line): `|StoreName||Title|Learning XML|Author|Erik T. RayBarnes and Noble Attribute` which is very different from the expected result  --  "*FYI, the real fun will be the real data.*" Why not post your question with the "real" data, then?

Comment: @JOATMON If this answer helped you solve your problem, then please [accept it](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). Or else edit your question and explain your "real" issue. Thanks.

Comment: Popping back in after ages, to answer the suggestion to post real data: simplest reason for that is a) it's too complex for where I was / am in the learning process, and b) it's client data so I'd have to do some major-league sanitation which would probably lead to me messing it up beyond belief. Thanks for the help earlier - I wound up having to leave this for a bit but will be revisiting it soon.